# How to set relief for ttk.Combobox?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, combobox, ttk

In Linux I need to set ttk.Combobox widget relief to *flat*. Following code does not work, the widget is rendered as *sunken*.

```
style.map('TCombobox', relief=[('readonly','flat')])
```

Is there a complete ttk widgets documentation available with all style tweaks, widget elements, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this : `ttk.Style().configure('TCombobox', relief='flat')`

If you have any problem you can check the [ttk documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html)

Comment: The widget interior changed to flat, but the border is still sunken. I need the exact opposite - to leave interior intact and change only the border style.

Answer (score 0):

The `Combobox.padding` has another style option: `shiftrelief`.

On my Windows Python 3.6 both style options have no effect at all.

`Combobox.padding` is a child of `Combobox.border`. Maybe the theme you use on Linux has options for `Combobox.border`.

```
style = ttk.Style()
style..theme_use('yourstylename')
style.layout('TCombobox')
style.element_options('Combobox.border')
```